# run jQuery after dynamic content is generated every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have an image map with tooltips that when clicked open the tooltip content in the right hand side of the page. The tooltip functionality is from litetooltip.js, and is working fine.

Inside the tooltip content will be a gallery that I've created, and will use jQuery to determine how many images are in the content, and if more than one, add the gallery arrows, add an 'active' class on the first image, then toggle the class through each image on left/right arrow click (I have not coded toggling the class as of yet).

The issue I'm having is that the jQuery I'm trying to use is not being applied after the tooltip click event. I've tried using .on() which will work on the first click, but once you click off the tooltip and back into it, it does not run again. I need for the script to run each time the tooltip is clicked.

I've also tried using delegate() which you can see commented out in the code, this did not run anything.

```js
//All tooltip content lives below
$('#ihotspot1').LiteTooltip({
  location: 'top',
  textalign: 'left',
  trigger: 'click',
  opacity: 1,
  padding: 0,
  shadow: 0,
  container: 'tooltips',
  issticky: true,
  title: '<div class="template ihotspot1">' +
    '<h4>Waterproofing Membrane</h4>' +
    '<div class="item-gallery">' +
    '<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.1Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="" />' +
    '<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.2Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_1" alt="" />' +
    '<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.3Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_2" alt="" />' +
    '<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.4Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_3" alt="" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<p>We start by broom sweeping the footing then spray a EPRO rubber polymer membrane to fill in all of the crevices. This goes far beyond building code, but we know this is a key factor in keeping your living space dry. This first step along with the 15 year warranty is just one way we prepare the foundation for years to come.</p> ' +
    '</div>'
});
$('#ihotspot2').LiteTooltip({
  location: 'top',
  textalign: 'left',
  trigger: 'click',
  opacity: 1,
  padding: 0,
  shadow: 0,
  container: 'tooltips',
  issticky: true,
  title: '<div class="template ihotspot2">' +
    '<h4>Waterproofing Membrane</h4>' +
    '<div class="item-gallery">' +
    '<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.1Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="" />' +
    '<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.2Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_1" alt="" />' +
    '<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.3Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_2" alt="" />' +
    '<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.4Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_3" alt="" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<p>We start by broom sweeping the footing then spray a EPRO rubber polymer membrane to fill in all of the crevices. This goes far beyond building code, but we know this is a key factor in keeping your living space dry. This first step along with the 15 year warranty is just one way we prepare the foundation for years to come.</p> ' +
    '</div>'
});



//$('.look-inside').delegate('click', '.redhotspot', function(){
//$('.hotspots').on('click', '.redhotspot', function() {
//$(document.body).on('click', '.redhotspot', function() {
$('.redhotspot').on('click', function() {
  var imageCounter = 0;
  $.each($('.template'), function(i) {
    //Display first each image
    $('.item-gallery img:first-child').addClass('active');
    imageCounter = $('.item-gallery img').length;
    //Arrows
    if (imageCounter != 1) {
      $('.item-gallery').after('<div class="left-arrow"></div><div class="right-arrow"></div>');

    }
    //Arrows click
    $('.right-arrow').click(function() {
      var currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('class');
      currentParent = currentParent.split(' ')[1];
      if ($('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery img:last-child').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery img:last-child').removeClass('active');
        $('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery img:first-child').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery .active').next().addClass('active');
        $('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery .active').prev().removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    $('.left-arrow').click(function() {
      var currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('class');
      currentParent = currentParent.split(' ')[1];
      if ($('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery img:first-child').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery img:first-child').removeClass('active');
        $('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery img:last-child').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery .active').prev().addClass('active');
        $('.' + currentParent + ' .item-gallery .active').next().removeClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
/**** look inside tooltip CSS ****/

.litetooltip-wrapper {
  font: inherit;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-arrow {
  border: none !important;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content {
  padding: 10px !important;
  background: #fff !important;
  color: inherit !important;
  min-width: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template {
  position: relative;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template h4 {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #154734;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.redhotspot {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 103;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #d11947;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.look-inside {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
  /* actual width of image*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 101;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.look-inside .img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 62.5%;
  /* image-height / width * 100 */
}

.look-inside img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 102;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .redhotspot {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
  }
}

#tooltip-clickoutside {
  z-index: 100;
}

.item-gallery img {
  display: none;
}

.item-gallery img.active {
  display: block;
}

.left-arrow:before {
  content: "<";
}

.right-arrow:before {
  content: ">";
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  top: 44px;
  height: 180px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  background: #000;
}

.right-arrow {
  left: 220px;
}

.left-arrow:before,
.right-arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: 'ETmodules';
  font-size: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-gallery {
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="look-inside">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img alt="Look Inside" src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/Breckenridge.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="hotspots">
    <div id="ihotspot1" class="redhotspot" style="top: 80%; left: 44.5%; cursor: pointer;">1</div>
    <div id="ihotspot2" class="redhotspot" style="top: 91.5%; left: 32.5%; cursor: pointer;">2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tooltips"></div>

<script src="https://www.inabrains.com/tooltip/js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.inabrains.com/tooltip/js/libs/jquery.app.ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.inabrains.com/tooltip/js/libs/eacd7d071f342c3d2855e17915b4c5223bd87f3b5778cf4bd630459a330ed1aa.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try calling $.on() from a parent and passing the selector as a parameter. I'm not familiar with how LiteTooltip works but if its dynamically recreating the ihotspot divs each click then the handler will either need to be re-added each time, or on an element further up the chain that isnt removed.

try:
$('.hotspots').on('click', '.redhotspot', function() { // ...

failing that go further up like:
$('body').on('click', '.redhotspot', function() { // ...

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @radcore I've tried implementing both of your solutions, and neither are working.

Comment: OK. It was worth a try.

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect everything I've tried to get the gallery to stay on every click. So far the only thing that is partially working is the simple on click event.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I've found a resolution! Seems a bit hackish, though.

I broke my click event into two separate functions - one for the actual click event `RefreshEventListener()`, and another for the image gallery `ImageGallery()`.
Then, after wrapping everything with document.ready, I added a `setInterval` to the click event function.

Below is the updated code

```js
//All tooltip content lives below
$('#ihotspot1').LiteTooltip({
 textalign: 'left',
 trigger: 'click',
 opacity: 1,
 padding: 0,
 shadow: 0,
 container: 'tooltips',
 issticky: false,
 title:
 '<div class="template ihotspot1">' +
 '<h4>Waterproofing Membrane</h4>' +
 '<div class="item-gallery">' +
'<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.1Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="" />' +
'<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.2Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_1" alt="" />' +
'<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.3Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_2" alt="" />' +
'<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.4Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_3" alt="" />' +
'</div>' +
 '<p>We start by broom sweeping the footing then spray a EPRO rubber polymer membrane to fill in all of the crevices. This goes far beyond building code, but we know this is a key factor in keeping your living space dry. This first step along with the 15 year warranty is just one way we prepare the foundation for years to come.</p>  ' +
 '</div>'
});
$('#ihotspot2').LiteTooltip({
 textalign: 'left',
 trigger: 'click',
 opacity: 1,
 padding: 0,
 shadow: 0,
 container: 'tooltips',
 issticky: false,
 title:
 '<div class="template ihotspot2">' +
 '<h4>Waterproofing Membrane</h4>' +
 '<div class="item-gallery">' +
'<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.1Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_0" alt="" />' +
'<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.2Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_1" alt="" />' +
'<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.3Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_2" alt="" />' +
'<img src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/1.4Waterproofing.jpg" class="image_1_3" alt="" />' +
'</div>' +
 '<p>We start by broom sweeping the footing then spray a EPRO rubber polymer membrane to fill in all of the crevices. This goes far beyond building code, but we know this is a key factor in keeping your living space dry. This first step along with the 15 year warranty is just one way we prepare the foundation for years to come.</p>  ' +
 '</div>'
});


   $(document).ready(function() {
  RefreshEventListener();
    
  function RefreshEventListener() {
    // Re-add event handler for all matching elements
    $(".redhotspot").one("click", function() {
   //alert("clicked");

   //update tooltip content with gallery if necessary
   if ($(".template").is(":visible")) {
     ImageGallery();
   }
    });
  }
  setInterval(RefreshEventListener, 0);
    
  function ImageGallery() {
    //Display first each image
    $(".item-gallery img:first-child").addClass("active");

    var imageCounter = 0;
    imageCounter = $(".item-gallery img").length;

    //Arrows
    if (imageCounter != 1) {
   $(".item-gallery").after(
     '<div class="left-arrow"></div><div class="right-arrow"></div>'
   );
    }

    //Arrows click
    $(".right-arrow").click(function() {
   var currentParent = $(this)
   .parent()
   .attr("class");
   currentParent = currentParent.split(" ")[1];
   if (
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery img:last-child").hasClass(
    "active"
     )
   ) {
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery img:last-child").removeClass(
    "active"
     );
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery img:first-child").addClass(
    "active"
     );
   } else {
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery .active")
    .next()
    .addClass("active");
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery .active")
    .prev()
    .removeClass("active");
   }
    });

    $(".left-arrow").click(function() {
   var currentParent = $(this)
   .parent()
   .attr("class");
   currentParent = currentParent.split(" ")[1];
   if (
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery img:first-child").hasClass(
    "active"
     )
   ) {
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery img:first-child").removeClass(
    "active"
     );
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery img:last-child").addClass(
    "active"
     );
   } else {
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery .active")
    .prev()
    .addClass("active");
     $("." + currentParent + " .item-gallery .active")
    .next()
    .removeClass("active");
   }
    });
  }
   });
```

```css
/**** look inside tooltip CSS ****/

.litetooltip-wrapper {
  font: inherit;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-arrow {
  border: none !important;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content {
  padding: 10px !important;
  background: #fff !important;
  color: inherit !important;
  min-width: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .tooltip-content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template {
  position: relative;
  }
.litetooltip-wrapper .template h4 {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #154734;
  padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.litetooltip-wrapper .template p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.redhotspot {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 103;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #d11947;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.look-inside {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
  /* actual width of image*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 101;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.look-inside .img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 62.5%;
  /* image-height / width * 100 */
}

.look-inside img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 102;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .redhotspot {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
  }
}

#tooltip-clickoutside {
  z-index: 100;
}

.item-gallery img {
  display: none;
}

.item-gallery img.active {
  display: block;
}

.left-arrow:before {
  content: "<";
}

.right-arrow:before {
  content: ">";
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  top: 44px;
  height: 180px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
   background: #000;
}

.right-arrow {
  left: 220px;
}

.left-arrow:before,
.right-arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: 'ETmodules';
  font-size: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-gallery {
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="look-inside">
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img alt="Look Inside" src="https://paynefh.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/Breckenridge.jpg">
  </div>
<div class="hotspots">
<div id="ihotspot1" class="redhotspot" style="top: 80%; left: 44.5%;">1</div>
<div id="ihotspot2" class="redhotspot" style="top: 91.5%; left: 32.5%;">2</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="tooltips"></div>

<script src="https://www.inabrains.com/tooltip/js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.inabrains.com/tooltip/js/libs/jquery.app.ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.inabrains.com/tooltip/js/libs/eacd7d071f342c3d2855e17915b4c5223bd87f3b5778cf4bd630459a330ed1aa.js"></script>
```